# Is it possible to use php exec and answer questions from the script?

Tags: php, linux, exec

Imagine I have a script.sh on my server that asks for your name. You run the script and it says:

```
what is your name?
```

then you input your name and it prints:

```
hello name!
```

Is it possible, using php exec, to run such a script? That is to exec the script and somehow answer the different questions it could have?

Hope I am clear. What I am really trying to do is automate the "git pull" command from our dev  server but it keeps asking for a username/password. I know I could use ssh certificate login to avoid that but my question still stands. Can I use exec() and answer future questions from the script.

Comment: Most posix commands provide switches or options so that no interaction is required. You can use PHP to collect that information and run it through exec() with escapeshellargs()

Comment: I do not think git pull is a posix command :(

Comment: One solution might be to set up a user to use ssh certificate login

Comment: @JonStirling yeah I know but I think its still interesting to know if this is feasable. Edited my question to make it clearer that I know of this solution.

Comment: No, it's not possible to interact with a script using exec(), system(), or passthru(). I imagine that's for security purposes.

Comment: @Iznogood In that case (keep in mind I haven't looked into this is a loooong time) it may be worth looking at [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) (though doing it direct through exec or other shell functions I don't believe is possible)

Comment: @MikeB oh well. Post it as a answer I'll wait and if its a concencus will give you your points.

Comment: @JonStirling will look into that seems interesting

Comment: @lznogood I’m trying to do the same thing (automate git pulls on a web server)! Did you happen to figure something out using PHP? I’ve been searching the web like crazy and would love to hear from you 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's worth noting that the better solution in your case is to use SSH keys for authentication. But, you might be able to pull this off with [PHP Expect](http://php.net/manual/book.expect.php).

```
ini_set("expect.timeout", -1);
ini_set("expect.loguser", "Off");

$stream = expect_popen("git pull");

while (true) {
    switch (expect_expectl ($stream, array (
            array ("username:", USERNAME),
            array ("password:", PASSWORD),
    ))) {
        case USERNAME:
            fwrite ($stream, "usename\n");
            break;
        case PASSWORD:
            fwrite ($stream, "secret\n");
            break;

        case EXP_TIMEOUT:
        case EXP_EOF:
            break 2;

        default:
            die ("Error has occurred!\n");
    }
}

fclose ($stream);
```

Comment: Wow, had no idea expect had been put into PHP. +1 for the un-expect-ed info.

Comment: learned something new today :) but i think what he is asking for is a script that will wait for keyboard input not input from a file stream

Comment: This is pretty much what I was asking for. Seems like my version of ubuntu server does not have expect_popen tho.. looking into that.

Comment: @Iznogood: You may have to install the libexpect library and/or install the Expect PHP package from PECL: http://pecl.php.net/package/expect.

Comment: Awarded you the answer. But since I could not get expect_popen to work I just made a shell scritp that used expect and voila works perfectly. Thank you! +1 too of course.

Answer (score 1):

For your question: One thing you can do, if you exctly know what is being asked to use a pipe
    exec("echo 'hello world' | some_command")
if you need more complex interaction look at popen(). popen gives you stream access to the process , so you can use fread/fwrite etc
But these won't work for your case as most ssh impleentations check for an interactive input using special APIs. What you can do there is either using keys or looking at ssh-agent.

Answer (score 1):

When you use php to execute a command, the command has required you answer single question for complete the process.

echo 'answer' | command

If You need to answer multi questions you may go to this link: [PHP execute command and answering questions for command](http://drupal.uwebweb.com/php-execute-command-and-answering-questions-command)